# JS illegal character exception... but nothing found in unicode viewer?

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I'm using DataTables with Moment.js because my table gets it's date and time values as integers but we need it displayed in "DD.MM.YY hh:mm:ss" format.
I followed [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) tutorial on how to setup Moment.js

When importing the required libraries I get an error, that both my files contain an illegal char (U+206E) in the 1st row, 4th char (I may add that I prettified the code using IntelliJs auto-formatter but the error was already there when it was a fresh download)....

[image: SyntaxError: illegal char U+206E in moment.min.js, line 1, char #4]

...but when I look at the text in a Unicode Viewer I get nothing out of the ordinary
(Site source: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php)

[image: unicode viewer for text, only displaying the visible text + spaces as dots]

What could be the issue here? Here are the first 5 rows for both files:

moment.min.js:

```
(function (a) {
function b(a, b, c) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 2:
            return null != a ? a : b;
```

datetime-moment.js:

```
(function (factory) {
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery", "moment", "datatables.net"], factory);
} else {
    factory(jQuery, moment);
```

**EDIT**: I noticed that when I imported another library I got a similar error, this time a U+2A2F char when importing date-eu.js, also stored locally. I had gotten the same error with the same char before i prettified the code for both libraries, could this be connected?

Comment: "_When importing the required libraries_" - Can you show us exactly how you are doing this, using a [mre] - the least amount of HTML needed to recreate the problem?

Comment: One point, as a side-note (I don't believe it is a solution): You may see old tutorials that refer to URLs without the protocol - for example: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js`. That is no longer recommended. Instead, always include the protocol: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js`. See [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for more background on this.